# how to update a column in force.com explorer

Tags: api, salesforce, soql

**SELECT  Name,  ProfileId, Id, Username FROM User** this is the select query to retrive data in Force.com explorer

Now I wan't to update a column how can I do this? update key word it self not working here please give the solution for this.
thanks in advance

Comment: I am trying to update from WinForm Application
using following query
Update Profile set Name='Standard User' where Id='00e90000001XQiYAAW'

Now I am getting following error
ERROR:MALFORMED_QUERY: unexpected token: Update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Salesforce you not write to update query same as in SQL.

Please use update method to update column of an object.

More information and sample please read following documents.

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_update.htm

Answer (score 0):

I found Solution it's working fine now, If any one haveing doubts ask me for Create,Update,Get functionalities

```
private void UpdateProfileId(string Id)
{
 SforceService sfs = new SforceService();
 var login = sfs.login(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"],ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"]);

 sfs.Url = login.serverUrl;
 sfs.SessionHeaderValue = new SessionHeader();
 sfs.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = login.sessionId;
 var userinfo = login.userInfo;

 QueryResult qr = null;
 sfs.QueryOptionsValue = new salesforce.QueryOptions();

 User[] UpdateUser = new User[1];
 User objuser = new User();
 objuser.Id = Id;
 objuser.ProfileId = "00e90000001CcTnAAK";
 UpdateUser[0] = objuser;

 try
 {
   SaveResult[] saveResults = sfs.update(UpdateUser);
   foreach (SaveResult saveResult in saveResults)
   {
    if (saveResult.success)
     {
       Console.WriteLine("Successfully updated Account ID: " +saveResult.id);
     }
   }
 }
}
```